Accidentally Changed Permalink Structure
I accidentally changed my permalink structure form "postname" to "plain" but when i realized all my articles that were ranking are disappeared so i changed it but nothing changed still everything is down. When i see google search console i found crawling graph is moving downwards so as impressions and clicks but i already did redirects to urls because I'm using rank math. This plugin did automatically redirects but sadly everything is down from one week now. Please help if anyone knows what should i do.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
